# How do I use a command to break this loop

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I have this code. It reads out a file. I want to be able to use a stop command on discord to stop the loop

```
@client.command()
async def read(ctx, message):
    with open(f'{message}.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line, end="")
            await ctx.send(f"{line}")
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a global variable called `is_stopped` which will be a boolean. In each iteration of the loop, it will check if `is_stopped` is true or not. Here's what I mean:

```py
global is_stopped
is_stopped = False

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global is_stopped
    is_stopped = True
    await ctx.send("stopped!")

@client.command()
async def read(ctx, message):
    with open(f'{message}.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not is_stopped:
                print(line, end="")
                await ctx.send(f"{line}")
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
            else:
                break
```